# How long will Rails sidekiq retry jobs for?

Tags: sidekiq

I have a failed sidekiq job due to some logic error. How many times will this job retry? Where do failed jobs go? Are failed jobs put back in the queue in redis?

Also, what exactly is a sidekiq process? How does sidekiq spin up one process to enqueue jobs and another to dequeue jobs? What is going on there on a high level?

Answer (score 2):

Not all answers to your questions, but some helpful information:

1. From sidekiq Wiki: "If you don't fix the bug within 25 retries (about 21 days), Sidekiq will stop retrying and move your job to the Dead Job Queue. You can fix the bug and retry the job manually anytime within the next 6 months using the Web UI...." - (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#best-practices)
2. If you want to monitor jobs in real time at `you-domain/sidekiq` (or whatever you set up) read this how to set up routes: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#sidekiq-web-does-not-render-correctly-in-production-but-works-fine-in-development
3. To kill failed jobs in development I run `$redis.flushdb` from rails console. This will cancel all queued jobs though. I never needed to kill one, but I'm sure it's possible somehow.
4. You can configure job retries by options from this wiki page: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#configuration
   example: 

   `sidekiq_options :retry => 5 # Only five retries and then to the Dead Job Queue`
5. And to avoid multiple entry-level issues read best practices page:   https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices
   Especially pay attention to point: **2. Make your job idempotent and transactional**

Overall they have very good wiki which answers most questions.

Comment: Here's a table with all the retry intervals:
https://gist.github.com/marcotc/39b0d5e8100f0f4cd4d38eff9f09dcd5